# What are the eigenvalues of $L_+$ and $L_-$?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, angular-momentum, operators, hilbert-space, eigenvalue

I'm studying angular momentum in quantum mechanics. My question involves the operators $L_+=L_x+iL_y$ and $L_-=L_x-iL_y$; in a problem I have a Hamiltonian, $H$, depending an $L_y$, $L^2$ and $L_z$. The solutions suggest to write $L_y$ as a combination of $L_+$ and $L_-$ and then, using the eigenvectors of $L_z$ and $L^2$, write the matrix associated with $H$, and then diagonalize the matrix. How is this possible? How can $L_y$ and $L_z$ be diagonalized in the same basis?
 Sorry for bad English.

Comment: After you diagonalize the Hamiltonian  the resulting eigenfunctions will no longer be eigenstates of both $L_y$ and $L_z$.

Comment: Note that the ladder operators $L_{\pm}$ are _not_ [normal operators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_operator), and hence are _not_ diagonalizable in an orthonormal basis (except for the singlet representation).

Comment: Perhaps you can post the question exactly and not "rephrase/interpret" it here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you write the matrix representation of $L_y$ in a basis where $L_z$ is diagonal, you should get (assuming $\ell=1$) something like
$$
\hat L_z=
\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 1 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & -1 \\
\end{array}
\right)\, ,\qquad
\hat L_y=\frac{1}{2i} \left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 0 & 1 & 0 \\
 -1 & 0 & 1 \\
 0 & -1 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right) \tag{1}
$$
Of course $\hat L_y$ is not a diagonal matrix there is nothing to prevent you from writing the Hamiltonian and diagonalize the resulting matrix.  The eigenstates will not be eigenstates of either $L_y$ or $L_x$ but that's not a big deal: they will be expressed as combinations of your basis eigenstates of $L_z$

However, since $a L_y+b L_z$ commutes with $L^2$, the latter will still be diagonal.